# take a character from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have problem with getting out a character or characters of a string in C++.

It was easy in python, for example I could take the first block of a string like this:

```
x = "Hello Word"
p = x[0]
```

now the `H` character would save in `p`.

Comment: "blocks of a string"? Are you asking about the characters of a string? (Note: the tag `block` states "Do not use")

Comment: No idea what you're asking.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Oh , sorry , I meant character @crashmstr

Comment: :D You should first try to write hello world program, not hello word

Comment: @KevinGH you might want to consider finding a book or course on C++ to start learning the basics.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, surely you mean a char (character?)

```
std::string x = "Hello Word";
char p = x[0]; //p now contains 'H'
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string for more detail (thanks for suggestion of link)